# Space between two background images

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image

I'm working on wordpress for the first time. And I'm trying to add background images to the title. The title should look like this.
[image]

Till now I'm able to achieve till this level.
[image]

I want to have space between two images, how to do that?
My CSS is

```
.page-id-157 .widget-title{
height: 45px;
padding-left:70px;

    background-image: url('images/stripe_red_diagonal.png'),url('images/logo_outline_black.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position:20px 10px;
    }
```

How to give space between two background images? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the `background-position` value for the 2nd image separated by a `,`

150px is the horizontal offset from the start point of the images and should be greater than the size of the first image.

```css
.widget-title {
  height: 45px;
  padding-left: 70px;
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/100x100'), url('http://placehold.it/100x100/333');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 20px 10px, 150px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="widget-title"></div>
```